# Custom validation on .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this

```
class ApprovalRequest
{
      public ApprovalGeneralInfo ApprovalGeneralInfo { get; set; }
      public List<Service> Services {get; set;}
}

class ApprovalGeneralInfo
{
   public string ApprovalID { get; set; }
}

class Service
{
        public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
        public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I need the `Service.ServiceCode` To be required if `ApprovalGeneralInfo.ApprovalID`  value ="Pharmacy"

its should be custom data annotation like :
`[CustomRequired("ApprovalGeneralInfo.ApprovalTypeID",ApprovalType.Pharmacy)]`

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly property and validate this in constructor.

```
 class Service
 {
    public string ServiceCode { get; }
    public string ServiceDescription { get; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// public constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Service(string serviceCode, string serviceDescription)
    {
        // custom validation rules
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceCode) && approvalGeneralInfo.ApprovalID == "Pharmacy")
            throw new ArgumentException("serviceCode must be set");
                
        ServiceCode = serviceCode;
        ServiceDescription = serviceDescription;
    }
 }
```

Comment: How can I access `approvalGeneralInfo.ApprovalID`  in the Service class

Comment: you cannot unless you pass the ApprovalGeneralInfo object Or its ApprovalId property to the service constructor

Comment: It depends on how class ApprovalGeneralInfo related to class Service and how objects created. For a more complete answer, you need to provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

When the hydrated request object is sent, before using the data - add a validation check;

```
 if ApprovalGeneralInfo.ApprovalID =="Pharmacy" && Services.Any(s => 
                                    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s.ServiceCode))
           //throw error
```

OR try using validation attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom ServiceCollection that you pass the ApprovalRequestInfo object to it.

then when you try to insert services you can validate the service as I did here:

```
class ApprovalRequest
{
    public ApprovalRequest(ApprovalGeneralInfo approvalGeneralInfo)
    {
        ApprovalGeneralInfo = approvalGeneralInfo;

        Services = new ServiceCollection(ApprovalGeneralInfo);
    }

    public ApprovalGeneralInfo ApprovalGeneralInfo { get; set; }
    public ServiceCollection Services {get; set;}
}

class ApprovalGeneralInfo 
{
    public string ApprovalID { get; set; }
}

class Service
{
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
}

class ServiceCollection:Collection<Service>
{
    private readonly ApprovalGeneralInfo _approvalGeneralInfo;

    public ServiceCollection(ApprovalGeneralInfo approvalGeneralInfo)
    {
        _approvalGeneralInfo = approvalGeneralInfo;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index,Service item)
    {
        if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

        if (_approvalGeneralInfo.ApprovalID.Equals("Pharmacy")) // you can validate here as you want
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ServiceCode))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Service code is required.");
            }
        }

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the instant of ApprovalRequest from the user when I add any constructor in this class doesn't work

Comment: sorry but I could not understand what do you want. if you want to validate the service object in your list based on a property on another object so the best approach is to create a custom Collection class that checks your other object property before any insert.